# Pybind Embedding the interpreter: Import numpy module failed at second time by Pybind11 in CPP

Tags: python, c++, numpy, cpython, pybind11

I am trying to embedding some python script into my cpp project with QT by using pybind11. Till now it is all fine since I start to import some third-party extension in python script (e.g. numpy).

Here is simple example of my code:

```
void myFuc()
{
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
    {
    py::exec(R"(
           import numpy as np
           foo = np.array([1,2,3])
           print(foo)
       )";
    }
```

myFun() will be executed by pressing a button from other part of my qt-program. By first click the function was executed correctly and I get the return: [1 2 3]. By second click I get the following error message and my program crashed:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pybind11::error_already_set'
  what():  SystemError: ../Objects/structseq.c:481: bad argument to internal function

At:
  /home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py(6): <module>
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(883): exec_module
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(703): _load_unlocked
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1006): _find_and_load_unlocked
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1027): _find_and_load
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1079): _handle_fromlist
  /home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py(10): <module>
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(883): exec_module
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(703): _load_unlocked
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1006): _find_and_load_unlocked
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1027): _find_and_load
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1079): _handle_fromlist
  /home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py(51): <module>
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(883): exec_module
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(703): _load_unlocked
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1006): _find_and_load_unlocked
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1027): _find_and_load
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1079): _handle_fromlist
  /home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py(141): <module>
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(883): exec_module
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(703): _load_unlocked
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1006): _find_and_load_unlocked
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1027): _find_and_load
  <string>(5): <module>
```

I guess this is caused by the following reason:
Description about the life time of python interpreter of Pybind11 [Link](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html)

So if I understand it correctly, that some third-party-extension of python can not properly unloaded after the shutdown of the interpreter and it cause error.

Then i found these two useful issues:
[Import module second time fails with numpy #3112](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/3112)
[cannot run two times a script importing PyQt5 #1702](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1702)

Then I've tried:

1. instead of using `py::scoped_interpreter guard{};`, i used `py::initialize_interpreter()` and `py::finalize_interpreter()` at the begin and end of the scope `py::exec()`, i got the same error as before.
2. use `py::gil_scoped_acquire acquire` try to keep my interpreter alive look like this:

```
void myFuc()
{
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
    {
    py::gil_scoped_acquire acquire; // not sure if I use it correctly??
    py::exec(R"(
           import numpy as np
           foo = np.array([1,2,3])
           print(foo)
       )";
    }
```

This would also not be help, i got the same error like above.

Operating system: ubuntu 22.04.1
Python-Version: 3.10
Numpy-Version: 1.24.3

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

After two day struggle with this topic I've solved the problem. In general if I want to call a python function e.g. 'import numpy' more than one time, it is a bad idea to use 'py::scoped_interpreter guard{};', i change my code like below:

```
void myFuc()
{
    py::initialize_interpreter();
    {
    py::gil_scoped_acquire acquire; // still didn't sure if this is neccessary??
    py::exec(R"(
           import numpy as np
           foo = np.array([1,2,3])
           print(foo)
       )";
    }
```

This should keep the interpreter alive, the interpreter can be destructed with  `py::finalize_interpreter()`.
I make a mistake at the beginning that the `py::initialize_interpreter()` was called twice that's why I got a crash. Hope this can help for the similar issue.